# Animations continue to run even when the control is detached from its parent

Tags: wpf, animation, parent

Is this intended behavior? If I have a Label animating across the screen and I remove it with `canvas1.Children.Remove(label)` it seems that the animation continues to run behind the scenes and even fires `AnimationCompleted` even though I have no references to the label or to the `DoubleAnimation` I used to animate it with. What if the animation was endless?

Do I really need to do my own bookkeeping and stop the animation myself when removing a control from its parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I really need to do my own bookkeeping

Yes, you can only `Animate` `Dependency` properties and `Dependency` properties are `static` so even if your `Control` is no longer referenced the `Animation` will continue.

Depending on the purpose of your `Animation` you may it may be as simple as setting the Animations `FillBehavior` to `Stop`

```
animation.FillBehavior = FillBehavior.Stop;
```

This will stop the animation `TimeLine` when it completes, but this is not always a great solution if you have repeating animations or animations that set certain values as when the animation stops the property animated will return to its original value immediately.

---

If `FillBehavior.Stop` does not work in your situation you call stop `Animations` and `Storyboards` in other ways.

If the `Animation` is a `Storyboard` you can call `StopStoryboard`

When you use `BeginStoryboard` you can supply a `Name`, which you can then use in `StopStoryboard`:

```
  <BeginStoryboard Name="myStoryboard" ......... />

  <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="myStoryboard" />
```

Trigger Storyboard example:

```
<Trigger>
   <Trigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="myStoryboard">
          <Storyboard ..... />
       </BeginStoryboard>
   </Trigger.EnterActions>
   <Trigger.ExitActions>
      <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="myStoryboard" />
   </Trigger.ExitActions>
</Trigger>
```

Or in code behind you can just call `Stop` on your storyboard:

```
myStoryboard.Stop();
```

---

If you are creating a simple Animation in code behind you can stop it by applying a `null` `TimeLine` to the `DependencyProperty` you animated.

Example:

```
// Start
myLabel.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, new DoubleAnimation(10.0, 100.0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));

// Stop
myLabel.BeginAnimation(Canvas.LeftProperty, null);
```

Comment: Thanks for this set of solutions, all great options to employ in various cases. I hadn't previously known about the null Timeline solution and had a tricky animation issue that it solved. +1 and cheers!